# Phonegap 3.0: how to deploy and emulate from command line?

Tags: ios, cordova, path, ios-simulator

I'm building an app for both Android and iOS using Phonegap. I got everything upgraded to Phonegap 3.0 and started out with the Android version. Now I'm ready to get going on the iOS version.

Or am I?

When you add the ios  platform to your project, it's not a problem to "add platform ios" or to "build". But it is completely unclear how to use the command line interface to actually deploy the test app to device or emulator.

When you attach a physical iOS device, and simply try this from the main project folder...

```
$ cordova emulate ios
```

You get a pretty clear answer: deploying to device is not possible in this version of Phonegap. That begs the question "What about emulator?"

The [docs page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_tools.md.html#iOS%20Command-line%20Tools) on the 3.0 command-line interface mentions you should enter the command

```
$ /path/to/my_new_project/cordova/run
```

I have finally been able to get this to work. The trick is to go the /platforms/ios subfolder of your Cordova app project. There you type "cordova run". Then in my case it starts building, although I get an unanticipated error about "ios-sim" not being installed.

```
[...]
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Error: ios-sim was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.5 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim into your path. Or 'brew install ios-sim' using homebrew: http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/
```

Fortunately that project has adequate documentation on how to install. However, even after adding the ios-sim directory to my $PATH, when I want to emulate I get the following error.

```
$ cordova emulate ios
[TypeError: Arguments to path.join must be strings]
```

The docs could be a lot clearer. The main iOS [platform configuration page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide) does not mention the (im)possibility of using the CLI for running on device or emulator, and the docs page for the CLI that I linked earlier only shows example of how to run on Android.

Comment: Does your path contain any spaces? I had this error when using the emulate android with a space in my sdk path.

Comment: [http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html#Command-Line%20Usage].This link shows the to emulate  your ios project after using this any error arises then it will be issue any spaces or the path will no the correctly setted